# Time out issue when I add 2 functions

Tags: cypress

new at cypress and I am watching a tutorial, the objective of the test is to locate the value on the google input search page, (textarea). And the guy on it have the code like:

```
describe("learn about locators", () => {
it("visit google page", () => {
   cy.visit("https://google.com");
 });
it("can locate button on page", () => {  
   cy.get("textarea");
 });
});
```

But in my case I receive error: Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: textarea, but never found it.

For me to work I made a small change removing the first it function:

```
describe("learn about locators", () => {
it("can locate button on page", () => {  
  cy.visit("https://google.com");
  cy.get("textarea");
 });
});`
```

But what is the difference? why I can't make it work as on the tutorial?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gw32p.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can tell Cypress that a particular **suite** of tests are to be considered coupled (dependent on each other).

The configuration `{testIsolation:false}` can be added as an option to `describe()`.

```js
describe("learning about coupled tests", {testIsolation:false}, () => {

  it("visit google page", () => {
    cy.visit("https://google.com");
  })

  it("can locate button on page", () => {  
    cy.get("textarea");               // context from previous test is available here
  })
})

describe("learning about isolated tests", {testIsolation:true}, () => {

  it("visit google page", () => {
     cy.visit("https://google.com");
  })

  it("should fail this test", (done) => {  
    cy.on('fail', () => done())       // asserting that the test is expected to fail
    cy.get("textarea");
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[Cypress recommends running your tests in isolation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-isolation) from one another. What this means in your particular case, is that actions done in the first test (such as visiting the website) are not maintained in the second test. This is why you have to add the `cy.visit()` to the second test in order to get the test passing.

Most likely, the person leading the tutorial has an older version of Cypress where Test Isolation was not enabled by default, or the person has disabled Test Isolation, which is strongly discouraged.

If there are shared setup steps for a test, which must be executed on every test, [it is recommended to use a `beforeEach()`](https://filiphric.com/cypress-basics-before-beforeeach-after-aftereach) function, instead of repeating the steps in each test.

```js
describe("learn about locators", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit("https://www.google.com");
  });
  
  it("can locate button on page", () => {  
    cy.get("textarea");
  });
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! for that clear and simple answer. GG